# In EmberJS, what is the function called to execute jQuery plugin after the templates are done rendering?

Tags: ember.js

I've tried "didInsertElement" but that didn't seem to work, the markup doesn't exist and then the jQuery plugin code executes too fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you provide a jsFiddle of your issue? Also, try doing:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  Ember.run.next(optionalContext, function() {
    // Your code here
  });
}
```

That will run your code at the end of the current runloop which should guarantee that all rendering and bindings have executed.

But please provide a jsFiddle so a more precise answer can be given.

Comment: Hi Roy, i'll try to setup a jsFiddle soon. But the specific plugin i'm trying to use is jQuery TinySort http://luis-almeida.github.com/jPages/

Comment: This just doesn't seem to work... I'm trying to initialise JqueryUI tabs from dynamic data, and the full markup is not being created when this runs. I've also tried using the run afterRender hook, and still, the full markup including all the child views, all the way down the tree is not created when these execute. I can't find any way of making my initialisation code run AFTER the markup has been fully created within the DOM, and all elements are available.
I'm convinced I'm doing something wrong, because this must be the most basic thing for integration with other libs.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're using the inbuilt jQuery selector on the view - this.$() - that will work even if the element hasn't been inserted yet.

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this.$().jQueryPlugin();
}
```